# Google test, Typed test, C++

Tags: c++, templates, googletest, typed

I am having trouble running a typed test for my struct.

So consider in my `test.cpp` I have a template struct

```
template<typename T>
struct Something {
    T value;

    // Constructors

};
```

Now I declare `typedefs` as mention in documentation.

```
using MyTypes =
    testing::Types<char, unsigned char, short int, unsigned short int, int,
                   unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int,
                   unsigned long long int, float, double, long double>;
```

Then I create the test suite and the typed test  for my struct.

```
TYPED_TEST_SUITE(Something,MyTypes);

TYPED_TEST(Something,arithmetics) {
  Something<TypeParam> smth;
  .....
}
```

But when I run this, I get compile error `error: only virtual member functions can be marked 'override' TYPED_TEST(Something,arithmetics) {`

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not deriving `Something` from `testing::Test`.

It [should look](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#typed-tests) like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Something : public testing::Test {
public:
    T value;

    // ...
};
```

Then inside `TYPED_TEST` you don't need to create an instance of this class, you already have it:

```
TYPED_TEST(Something, Arithmetics) {
    EXPECT_EQ(this->value, 0);
}
```